# No Class Def Found Error org/gradle/cli/CommandLineConverter

Tags: java, gradle

When I'm trying to build my gradle project, it gives me this error. 
Following is the stack trace of error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/cli/CommandLineConverter
>   Process 'Gradle Test Executor 2' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'Gradle Test
>   Executor 2' finished with non-zero exit value 1.

FYI, Gradle verson is 4.1

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong or what I'm missing?

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError as the error say.. no class definition is found... can you provide more info? full error stack or possible a repo so we can reproduce the error..

Comment: try to set GRADLE_HOME environment variable.

Comment: GRADLE_HOME is already there. @Altmish-E-Azam